# How to get the shortest latLng on geocoder in PHP?

Tags: php, google-maps

Hello I have list of Destination and all I need to do is to accept the origin in LatLng and get the shortest route between on my list...  I don't know any procedural or any tutorial... i've readed the google but I don't know how to do that on PHP.. sorry I'm still student and had a bad time learning on this...

All I want is I pass latLng then inside the function return the destination of the shortest one...

I created that on HTML but it's not correct because I just want a webservice not a UI style... because I am trying to pass it on the mobile app.. please need help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: how many destinations do you have?